# What happens if someone steals the authrization code in Oath2 flow

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Please refer to this video, specifically from 20.00 to 25.00.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/new-authentication-model-for-web-mobile-and-cloud-applications/

The work flow he describes is this:
Client app connects to authorization end point through the browser. User enters credentials, and authserization server authenticates the user and sends the auth code using a re-direct. Client app intercepts the browser activity and extracts the auth code. A new request is made to token end point together with this auth code, client id and few other information. In return, app gets access and refresh token.

What stops some one from stealing the auth token in the first step (say through browser history), and then contacting the token end point to get access and refresh tokens?

Answer (score 1):

First off authorization code is only good for about 3 minutes normally.  Second authorization code can only be used once.  Third redirect uri must be a valid one that was registered for this client on the oauth server

1. The client initiates the flow by directing the resource owner's
   user-agent to the authorization endpoint.  The client includes
   its client identifier, requested scope, local state, and a
   redirection URI to which the authorization server will send the
   user-agent back once access is granted (or denied).
2. The authorization server authenticates the resource owner (via
   the user-agent) and establishes whether the resource owner
   grants or denies the client's access request.
3. Assuming the resource owner grants access, the authorization
   server redirects the user-agent back to the client using the
   redirection URI provided earlier (in the request or during
   client registration).  The redirection URI includes an
   authorization code and any local state provided by the client
   earlier.
4. The client requests an access token from the authorization
   server's token endpoint by including the authorization code
   received in the previous step.  When making the request, the
   client authenticates with the authorization server.  The client
   includes the redirection URI used to obtain the authorization
   code for verification.
5. The authorization server authenticates the client, validates the
   authorization code, and ensures that the redirection URI
   received matches the URI used to redirect the client in
   step (C).  If valid, the authorization server responds back with
   an access token and, optionally, a refresh token.

[#section-4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)

**Oauth flow**

Lets do this with some correct terminology.

- Client = your application
- authority= identity or oauth2 server (authority)
- resource owner = user whos data you wish to access.

Resource owner loads client, client notices that resource owner is not authorized.  Resource owner contacts authority identifying itself using a client id and possibly a client secret and sending a redirect uri, and requests scopes.  *(some of the things sent depend upon the setup of the auth server)*

Authority notices this resource owner is not logged in prompts them to log in.  Resource owner logs in and checks what scopes the client originally requested.  Prompts resource owner to grant client access to said scopes.

[image]

Resource owner consents to access.  Authority returns to the client an Authorization code.

Client says nice i have an authorization code and returns to the authority the authorization code and its client id and secret.   This way the Authority knows that this is in fact the client that the resource owner authorized.

Authority then returns an access token back to the client that it can use for the next hour.

Access tokens are not then re-validated.  So if someone stole this access token they would be able to use it until it expires.

Comment: none of this eliminate the issue I highlighted. Anyone stealing an unused auth code with in this time frame can gain access to tokens. I dont know why redirect uri is relevant here?

Comment: Unless the person stealing the unused auth code in the 3 minutes its active has a valid redirect URI registered on the server that they can have the refresh token returned to they wont be able to get anything back.   Some oauth servers even require that you send the client secret as well when exchanging the authorization code.

Comment: As DaImTo mentioned, the `/token` endpoint requires either authentication (client secret for matching the client ID of the `/auth` request) or requires [PKCE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636) which serves as a one-time password. So even if an auth code gets stolen, the attacker still needs the attacked client's password or a `code_verifier` to get tokens.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo. When you say client authenticates with authorization server, what really happens? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @DaImTo Could you please elaborate what you mean by Client authnticates with authorization server?

Comment: how can you say client secret is a secret when client binary is public? Its not that difficult to find the embedded client secret from the native client binary. So your explanation works when the app in concern is a web app where access token are requested by the backed (where a secret can be kept a secret). For native clients, this would not work. After reading some more I came across this - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636 which explains this issue and how it is solved. Essentially, we need to use PKCE extension to OAuth2 for native clients. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Thats why client credentials should not be embedded into anything.